# Switching or selecting the Object associated with ObData (Mesh)

Tags: mesh, objects, outliner

Hopefully someone can help.
I want to use the Outliner to help select a number of Objects based on the ObData name and then organise them into collections.

I used ALT + D to duplicate instances of a number of objects.  Unfortunately, to create iterations of the original rock, I Shift + D duplicated and did not change the name.  So the original objects were named rock.001, rock.002 and rock.003.
All the duplicated instances have names rock.038, rock.201 and so on.
The ObData have names that match the original geometry:Cube.001, Cube.002, Cube.003
I want to now organise the rocks into Collections based on the original geometry.
In the Outliner, I can search by name and I can select the Meshes (ObData?).  However, I don't believe I can't only move the ObData to a new collection, I need to go up the hierarchy to the object node.
Is this possible? If so, how would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the one answer.
Select the original object that was duplicated and then use:

Select > Select Linked > Object Data (Shift L)

However, what happens if you have inadvertently deleted the Original Object?